# Unable to install openjdk-13-jdk-headless=13~30-1 using base image debian:buster

Tags: java, python, docker, debian, debian-buster

Unable to install  openjdk-13-jdk-headless=13~30-1 using base image debian:buster

Reading package lists...
+ apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openjdk-13-jdk-headless=13~30-1
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-13-jdk-headless

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenJDK 13 is not available from the "buster" repo.  It is only available in "bullseye" (testing) and "sid" (unstable).

(See https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=openjdk-13)

Alternatively, you can download an OpenJDK Java 13 binary release as a "tar.gz" file from https://jdk.java.net/archive/ and install from that.

Note that Java 13 is now superseded, and will be end-of-life in September 2020.

Comment: does that tar.gz contain the headless version?

Comment: I don't know.  Try it and see.  (I'm not even sure that it is a meaningful question.  The distinction between headless and non-headless packages in Debian, Ubuntu, etc is most likely in the OS package dependencies that they list.  But the OpenStack tarball distros won't have package dependencies at all.)